# How can I implement SQL statement to LINQ in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2012

Good day

I need to interpret the following SQL to LINQ.

```
select 
      t1.req_no,
      t1.seq_no,
      t1.quantity,
      t1.uom,
      t1.item_name,
      t2.event_date 
from tb_cs_test t1, tb_cs_test2 t2 where (t1.req_no = 1 and t2.req_no = 1 );
```

I use MVC and with this SQL Statement i need to throw the requested fields based on the condition that I put

Thanks

Comment: What you tried so far? What is your class structure?

Comment: This is already Linq... can you explain a bit more, give us some context? Where did you obtain this snippet, and what do need to do with it.

Comment: @Glubus The posted code is SQL, not Linq.

Comment: question: *why* do you need to refactor it into LINQ? there are good tools to take your existing, fully working, parameterized SQL and run them efficiently and conveniently - without having to pay the overheads of expression-tree construction, inspection, and query generation associated with LINQ; could you perhaps just use Dapper here, for example, then it is just `var data = connection.Query<SomeTypeThatLooksCloseEnough>(@"your sql here", new { /* named args here, as an object initializer */});`

Comment: Sorry the code that i put is used in PLSQL so i need to do the same but for MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a `JOIN`:

```
from t1 in tb_cs_test 
join t2 in tb_cs_test2 
on t1.req_no equals t2.req_no
where t1.req_no = 1
select new {
  t1.req_no,
  t1.seq_no,
  t1.quantity,
  t1.uom,
  t1.item_name,
  t2.event_date 
}
```

Comment: This works fine! Thanks